# get, insert and replace string in iframe tiny texteditor

Tags: javascript, string, iframe, replace, rich-text-editor

i have textarea with ID xacta,

and this simple tiny text editor which create iframe of my textarea.

```
var editorxacta = new TINY.editor.edit("editorxacta", {
id: "xacta",
width: 860,
height: 180,
cssclass: "tinyeditor",
controlclass: "tinyeditor-control",
rowclass: "tinyeditor-header",
dividerclass: "tinyeditor-divider",
controls: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "|", "subscript", "superscript", "|", "outdent", "indent", "|", "leftalign",
    "centeralign", "rightalign", "blockjustify", "|", "hr", "link", "unlink"],
footer: false,
xhtml: true,
bodyid: "editorxacta",
cssfile: "css/style-adnx.css"
```

});

now i can get, insert and replace text in textareafield:

document.getElementById('xacta').value = "any string" - notwork
document.getElementById('editorxacta').value = "any string" - notwork

please helpme how can i control, get, insert or replace strings value in my textarea in iframe of tinytexteditor?

thankyou veri much for any suggestion, Jozef

Comment: hi, i resolved it with niceditor and this code:

Comment: for insert or replace:
$('#xacta').focus(); 
nicEditors.findEditor('xacta').nicCommand('InsertHTML', value);